# How to have bottom line programmatically just like in default edittext with gradientdrawable in android

Tags: android, android-studio

It will draw a bottom underline and i want to simply achieve below xml code by using gradientdrawable, I am trying to have custom edit text class which used in xml and set some property like bottom line color or others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-6dp"
        android:right="-6dp"
        android:top="-6dp">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I want it to be done through code using gradientdrawable class as i am calling a function which return created drawable.

Answer (score 0):

First create gradient file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="180" android:startColor="#7c0000" android:endColor="#ff9a9a"/>
</shape>
```

and than add it here :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" android:gravity="bottom" android:height="2dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I want it to be done through code using gradientdrawable class as i am calling a function which return created drawable.

Comment: if you want it with code try this  View layout = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
            new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd); 

title.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

Comment: or try this    int h = v.getHeight();
    ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h, Color.parseColor("#330000FF"), Color.parseColor("#110000FF"), Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);

Comment: not working previously i'am using this code in custom edittext class but it will draw a line on center of editext not bottom so text overlapped with line `private fun getDrawable(bgColor: Int): Drawable {
        val gd = GradientDrawable()
        gd.getPadding(Rect(-6,-6,-6,0))
        gd.shape = GradientDrawable.LINE
        gd.setStroke(strokeWidth.toDP(context), bgColor)
        return gd
    }`